# WordPress database set up with rest api

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I want use WordPress to develop a e-commerce website. I know basics about Wordpress like how to create blog or website. But I don’t know how to create database and relationship between tables, rest api etc. How can I set up my database and performing CRUD using rest api?

Comment: there is already a solution like woocommerce (https://woocommerce.com/) based on wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make an  ecommerce site, its better not re-invent the wheel, install woocommerce. If you are tryng to use wordpress as a development framework, try https://typerocket.com/ - This requiere not only knowledge of wordpeess, but php and laravel too. Wordpress , out of the box, together with JWT PLugin will give you a way to use it as a RBAC - Typerocket will give you the MVC structure. https://lumberjack.rareloop.com/ is another one. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Consult the Wordpress REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Then for features the API doesn't offer you will either have to learn to program and make your own API or hire a developer to do it.